# Can't understand array error

Tags: java, arrays

I just read the intro to arrays section in my AP Java book and tried the following example however I get an error and cant understand why.

Code:

```
public static void arrayT(int i){
  String[] alphabet = new String[5];
  alphabet[0] = "a";
  alphabet[1] = "c";
  alphabet[2] = "x";
  alphabet[3] = "b";
  alphabet[4] = "d";
  alphabet[5] = "e";
  System.out.println(alphabet[i]);
}
```

Main:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
  arrayT(2);
}
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
at Main.arrayT(Main.java:18)
at Main.main(Main.java:36)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String[] alphabet = new String[5];
```

The above statement allocates an array with a capacity of 5.  Valid indecies are 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4.

Index 5 is out of bounds.  Thus:

```
  alphabet[5] = "e";
```

throws the exception.

Answer (score 1):

`String[] alphabet = new String[5];` creates an array of length 5, that is it has indexes 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and exactly five elements in it. You are trying to access an element which isn't there, under index 5.

Answer (score 0):

Array defined is of length 5, and with `alphabet[5] = "e";` you are trying to add 6'th element to array. Either define array with legnth as 6

```
String[] alphabet = new String[6];
```

Or remove last line of code

```
alphabet[5] = "e"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you declare the array with length 5 but you assign 6 values to it.

alphabet[5] = "e";. This one causes 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5'

Try to set the length of array with length 6. Then you will get the right result.

**String[] alphabet = new String[6];**

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void arrayT(int i){
  String[] alphabet = new String[5];
  alphabet[0] = "a";
  alphabet[1] = "c";
  alphabet[2] = "x";
  alphabet[3] = "b";
  alphabet[4] = "d";
  alphabet[5] = "e";
  System.out.println(alphabet[i]);
}
```

in this when you declared statement

```
 String[] alphabet = new String[5];
```

then ur String Array size is 5 i.e 0-4(including 0 then total is 5 elements can be added)

so u have to increase the size of String array to 6 so as to add 6 elements

```
 String[] alphabet = new String[6];
```

Comment: please write "you" not "u"